# How to make connection with mysql server on localhost?

Tags: go

I want to make a new connection with the sql server on localhost so that I can able to get the data from the sql server. but there is some problem while doing connection.

error :- `[mysql] 2019/02/11 15:30:00 driver.go:81: net.Error from Dial()': dial tcp serverPort:3306: connect: connection timed out`

And the code I'm using is

```
func ConnectMsqlDb() (db *sql.DB, err error) {
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", 
    fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:"+SqlDbPort+")/"+SqlDatabase, 
    SqlUsername, SqlPassword, SqlServerPort))
fmt.Println("OPEN", db, err)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
//defer db.Close()
fmt.Println("PING:-", err)
err = db.Ping()
fmt.Println("PING:-", err)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return db, nil
}
```

Can you help me to get out from this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `serverPort` is the correct hostname? Seems odd to me, especially since the title says you want to connect to `localhost`.

Comment: @Peter my project is on localserver but I want to connect that project to the remote server

Comment: @Peter If you check correctly `serverPort` is DB port not hostname. `SqlServerPort` is correct hostname and being replaced with constant.

Comment: @surajprogrammez, the error message clearly shows that `serverPort:3306` is being dialed, so `SqlServerPort` is set to `"serverPort"` (or some value that implements fmt.Stringer).

Comment: @Peter yes so most probably he has `serverPort` as value of `SqlServerPort` instead of IP/DNS of database server

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a *remote* server you need its full address:

```
<username>:<pw>@tcp(<HOST>:<port>)/<dbname>
```

In your example I don't see the host anywhere, so it tries to connect to a server running on localhost (with port given by `SqlServerPort`).

[A simple connection example](http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html):

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/hello")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

You'll need to replace `127.0.0.1` with the actual IP address (or hostname) of your remote server.

Comment: He's replacing it with `SqlServerPort` he might have this constant defined somewhere but this is not the problem as far as I see. `dial tcp serverPort:3306: connect: connection timed out` Connection is timing out so this means something is wrong with DB server since the request is just being timed out.

Comment: @eliBendersky I'm giving the proper address but I don't want to connect it with local server I want to connect it with the remote server but it will gives me the error of time out.

Comment: @puneet55667788: are you sure you're giving the proper address? Print the values of all `Sql*` vars before the `sql.Open` statement is executing. Also you keep repeating "I don't want to connect it with local server I want to connect it with the remote server" but I have no idea what that means, sorry. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @EliBendersky it means that I want to connect remote server sql database which is having a unique address with my code which is running on local server.

Comment: @puneet55667788: that's what I understood. Look at the last line in my answer. I think your `SqlServerPort` has a bad value, probably `serverPort:3306`. `serverPort` is not a valid remote host address - you have to populate this variable with a valid one. Try to print out all your variables used in building the connection